# dtreeviz : Decision Tree Visualization : TypeError': <=' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'

Tags: python, dtreeviz

I am trying to use the dtreeviz package to build decision tree graph but I get an `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'`. All the input values are as per the the below dtreeviz signature and code is given below. What could be causing the error ?

```
dtreeviz.model(
    model,
    X_train,
    y_train,
    tree_index: int = None,
    feature_names: List[str] = None,
    target_name: str = None,
    class_names: (typing.List[str], typing.Mapping[int, str]) = None,
) -> dtreeviz.trees.DTreeVizAPI
```

Code:

train_IRIS data link - https://www.mediafire.com/file/r5dmkcyq3y8o65g/train_IRIS/file

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn import tree
import dtreeviz

train_data = pd.read_csv('./train_IRIS').iloc[:, 1:]
test_data = pd.read_csv('./test_IRIS').iloc[:,1:]

X_train = train_data[train_data.columns[:-1]]
y_train = train_data['Class_Label']

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

features_names = list(train_data[train_data.columns[:-1]])
class_array = np.unique(train_data['Class_Label'])

viz_model = dtreeviz.model(clf,
                           X_train=X_train.values, 
                           y_train=LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y_train),
                           feature_names=features_names,
                           target_name="Class_Label",
                           class_names=class_array)

v = viz_model.view()     # render as SVG into internal object 
v.show()
```

Error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 18
      9 clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
     11 viz_model = dtreeviz.model(clf,
     12                            X_train=X_train.values, 
     13                            y_train=LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y_train),
     14                            feature_names=features_names,
     15                            target_name="Class",
     16                            class_names=class_array)
---> 18 v = viz_model.view()     # render as SVG into internal object 
     19 v.show()

File ~\anaconda3\anaconda-py\envs\data-science\lib\site-packages\dtreeviz\trees.py:531, in DTreeVizAPI.view(self, precision, orientation, instance_orientation, show_root_edge_labels, show_node_labels, show_just_path, fancy, histtype, leaftype, highlight_path, x, max_X_features_LR, max_X_features_TD, depth_range_to_display, label_fontsize, ticks_fontsize, fontname, title, title_fontsize, colors, scale)
    529 if self.shadow_tree.is_classifier():
    530     class_values = self.shadow_tree.classes()
--> 531     if np.max(class_values) >= n_classes:
    532         raise ValueError(f"Target label values (for now) must be 0..{n_classes-1} for n={n_classes} labels")
    533     color_map = {v: color_values[i] for i, v in enumerate(class_values)}

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```